# Social Signout not working in conjunction with OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, owin

I created an MVC Web Application with OpenIdConnect authentication (for Azure Authentication) and Authentication providers for Google, Facebook and Microsoft Account.

The Configuration in StartupAuth looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        if (Config.TaskboardUserSource == Config.DirectoryService.AzureAD)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0),
                SlidingExpiration = true,

                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = Config.ClientId,
                    Authority = string.Format("{0}common", Config.AadInstance),
                    UseTokenLifetime = false,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Config.ClientId, Config.AppKey);
                            string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}{1}", Config.AadInstance, tenantID), new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                                code,
                                new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
                                credential,
                                Config.GraphResourceID).Result;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                            // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                            // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },


                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                            context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });

            var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = Config.FBAppId,
                AppSecret = Config.FBAppSecret,
                UserInformationEndpoint = Config.FBUserInformationEndpoint

            };
            facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Config.GoogleClientId,
                ClientSecret = Config.GoogleClientSecret
            });

            var microsoftOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Config.MSAppId,
                ClientSecret = Config.MSAppSecret,
            };
            microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("wl.basic");
            microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("wl.emails");
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftOptions);
        }
    }
```

All authentication options work fine.

When I want to signout, the only signout working is OpenIdConnect Signout.
For all other authentication providers, the cookie is still available and just by clicking the "Logon" Button the secured pages are shown without asking for a password.

My Signout looks like this:

```
    public void SignOut()
    {
        string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
             new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                       .Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes()
                       .Select(o => o.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

How can I make sure the user is signed out and gets redirected to the start page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I inserted a switch case statement in my signout code to do the signout for every logonprovider it finally works. Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> SignOut()
    {
        var currentUser = await UserService.CurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            var redirectUrl = Request.GetBaseUrl();
            var loginProviders = new string[] {
                        "Google",
                        "TwoFactorRememberBrowser",
                        "TwoFactorCookie",
                        "ExternalCookie",
                        "ApplicationCookie"
                };
            switch (currentUser.LoginProvider)
            {
                case LogonProvider.FacebookProviderKey:
                    {
                        loginProviders = new string[] {
                        "Facebook",
                        "TwoFactorRememberBrowser",
                        "TwoFactorCookie",
                        "ExternalCookie",
                        "ApplicationCookie" };
                        break;
                    }
                case LogonProvider.GoogleProviderKey:
                    {

                        loginProviders = new string[] {
                        "Google",
                        "TwoFactorRememberBrowser",
                        "TwoFactorCookie",
                        "ExternalCookie",
                        "ApplicationCookie" };
                        //return new RedirectResult($"https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout");
                        break;
                    }
                case LogonProvider.MicrosoftProviderKey:
                    {
                        loginProviders = new string[] {
                        "Microsoft",
                        "TwoFactorRememberBrowser",
                        "TwoFactorCookie",
                        "ExternalCookie",
                        "ApplicationCookie" };
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        loginProviders = new string[] {
                        "Office365",
                        "TwoFactorRememberBrowser",
                        "TwoFactorCookie",
                        "ExternalCookie",
                        "ApplicationCookie" };
                        break;
                    }
            }

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, loginProviders);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```